# What version of C# does add-type use

Tags: powershell, c#

I sometimes use add-type on machines where there is no c# compiler.  Most of the time it is OK because it is just simple stuff but occasionally I get a "feature not supported" or equivalent message.  I take the code back to my 2019/2022 compiler and it compiles.

So what is the problem?  The only thing I can think of is powershell is using an older version of the C#/VB compiler but how do I find out which one it is using?

If I know what version it is using I can use a compiler that supports that version to check the code if I get an error and find a way around it.  I know it is sad but I hava all the compilers from 2010 to 2022.

Comment: In 5.1 it uses c# 5

Comment: If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.  That would be VS2012/2013

Comment: see the linked answer, it has more details

Comment: The linked answer applies to _Windows PowerShell_. As for [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): It seems that whatever .NET (Core) version underlies a given PowerShell version implies the C# language version used, as shown at [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). For instance, since v7.3.x is built on .NET 7, `Add-Type` supports C# 11 there.

Comment: I'm using Powershell 5.1 but it is using C# 4.0.303919.  Just get add-type to print `typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion`.  It is the same on default windows 10 (powershell 5.1)  and Linux (powershell 7.4.0).  Quite annoying that stuff like Convert was only introduced on version 5.